# Is the multivariable function Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f: R^{k} \to R $

$f(x)= \ln(1+||x||)$

I concluded that this function is continuous, because it is a composition of continuous functions. I don't really know how to prove it is Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of concavity, the logarithm satisfies $\ln(b)-\ln(a)\leq(b-a)/a$ and $\ln(a)-\ln(b)\leq(a-b)/b$. This shows that $|\ln(b)-\ln(a)|\leq|b-a|/\min\{a,b\}$. Consequently
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\frac{|1+\|x\|-(1+\|y\|)|}{\min\{1+\|x\|,1+\|y\|\}}\leq|\|x\|-\|y\||.$$